# Asymptotic form of the function doesn't satisfy original differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, bessel-functions

Modified Bessel function of the first kind $I_0$ is defined as a solution of the [differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html)
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}-y=0. $$
For large arguments it has the [asymptotic form](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40)
$$I_0(x)\rightarrow \frac{e^x}{ \sqrt{2\pi x}}.$$ 
Substituting it back into the original equation we get 
$$\sqrt{2}e^{x}\frac{1}{8\sqrt{\pi}x^{5/2}}=0,$$
which is clearly nonsence. What am I missing ?

In the comments I was told that what is important is the ratio of the computed LHS and original approximation. Could you please tell why is that so and provide some reference? 
Is there some general way to know if some function is asymptotic approximation to the solution  given the computed LHS ?

Comment: Because the asymptotic form isn't the Bessel function it is an approximation.

Comment: The asymptotic form is just an approximation, so it shouldn't be that surprising that it doesn't exactly solve the original equation.

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt solve it even approximately. It should be something <<1 in the left side of the final equation for large x then.

Comment: `It should be something <<1 in the left side of the final equation for large x` What makes you think that? It should be enough that the expression is of a smaller order than the original approximation

Comment: @Dylan if I plot $I_{0}$ and its approximation for large enough $x$ they look identical. How can it be that one of them solves the equation and the other does not ? Even more, $e^{x}$ in the last expression diverges for large $x$.

Comment: The approximation has nothing to do with the differential equation. It is just an approximation.

Comment: @Dylan if I slightly perturb the $I_{0}$ function it will still satisfy the equation approximately. Why the limiting form does not ?

Comment: They only look identical because to see them at all for large $x$, the scale of the plot must be minuscule. If you plot the difference between $I_0$ and the approximation, you'll see that that grows in magnitude pretty fast.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer they are identical in logarithmic scale too.

Comment: Try plotting their difference. You'll see that it grows quite quickly

Comment: @Dylan I see. So that is why it doesn't solve the equation ?

Comment: The difference is neither close to $0$ or $I_0(x)$, so it cannot solve the equation (not even approximately). From linearity, it follows that the approximation must also behave the same way. It is still a good approximation, though, as their ratio approaches $1$ very quickly.

Comment: The relative error is of size $O(x^{-2})$ if you take what you computed for  the left side and divide it by the approximaton. For large $x$ this becomes relatvely small.

Comment: @LutzL +1 That's what I tried to express, but you worded it much better

Comment: @ LutzL Yes, but I should compare the left side with zero, not with the approximation, or am I mistaken ?

Comment: You're comparing the ratio between the computed LHS and the approximation, to $0$

Comment: @Dylan Yes, but why should I care about the ratio ?

Comment: I mean where does it come from ?

Comment: Given that there has been a lot of discussion in the comments, could you reformulate your question to focus on any confusion you still have now?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas I'm still confused about this ratio thing. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified Bessel function of the first kind $I_0$ is defined as a solution of the differential equation $(1)$.
$$ \frac{d^2 I_0(x) }{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dI_0(x)}{dx}-I_0(x)=0. \tag 1$$
For large arguments it has the asymptotic form :
$$I_0(x)\rightarrow f(x)=\frac{e^x}{ \sqrt{2\pi x}} \tag 2$$ 
$f(x)$ is not solution of Eq.$(1)$ because $f(x)\neq I_0(x)$

So, it should be nonsence to expect that substituting it back into the original equation would get $0.$

In fact, $f(x)$ is solution of the equation :
$$ \frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{df(x)}{dx}-\left(1+\frac{1}{4x^2}\right)f(x)=0. \tag 3$$
In comparing Eq.$(3)$ to Eq.$(1)$, we see that they are close one from the other.

Of course, $\frac{1}{4x^2}$ is small compared to $1$.

But  $\frac{f(x)}{4x^2}=\frac{e^x}{ \sqrt{2\pi}\:x^{5/2}} $ is not small due to the exponential.

Nevertheless, $\frac{f(x)}{4x^2}$ is small compared to $f(x)$.

This means that the relative deviation is small, while the absolute deviation is large.

This is strengthen by the asymptotic series expansion :
$$I_0(x)\sim\frac{e^x}{ \sqrt{2\pi x}}\left(1+\frac{1}{8x^2} +\frac{9}{128x^4}+...\right)$$ 
"Asymptotic series" doesn't mean that the absolute deviation tend to $0$. It means that the relative deviation tends to $0$.

If we compare the graphs of $I_0(x)$ and $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{ \sqrt{2\pi x}}$ in a range of large $x$, they cannot be distinguished one from the other because, by necessity, the scale of graphing is very large. The absolute difference between both is not visible at large scale, even with a large absolute difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Given the last expression in my post how could one know that the function I used to obtain it is asymptotic approximation to the solution?

Comment: One expand the exact solution into series : $I_0(x)\sim\frac{e^x}{ \sqrt{2\pi x}}\left(1+\frac{1}{8x^2} +\frac{9}{128x^4}+...\right)$. The main term $\frac{e^x}{ \sqrt{2\pi x}}$ is the asymptotic approximation.

Comment: What happens when I plug it back into original equation? It must me something special compared to some random function.

Comment: Not at all. It is well known that plugging back the asymptotic function into the original ODE never satisfies the equation. It satisfies a slightly different ODE. You can see this slightly different ODE in my answer. All is straightforward without something random.

Answer (score 1):

Using the known form of the asymptote, consider
$$
u =\ln(e^{-x}\sqrt xy(x))= -x +\frac12\ln x
+\ln y(x)
$$
Then
$$
u'(x)=-1+\frac1{2x}+\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}
$$
and
\begin{align}
u''(x)&=-\frac1{2x^2}+\frac{y''(x)}{y(x)}-\frac{y'(x)^2}{y(x)^2}\\
&=-\frac1{2x^2}+\frac{y-\frac{y'}{x}}{y}-\left(u'+1-\frac1{2x}\right)^2\\
&=-\frac1{2x^2}+1-\frac{u'}{x}-\frac1x+\frac1{2x^2}-u'^2-1-\frac1{4x^2}-2u'+\frac{u'}{x}+\frac1x\\
&=-u'(x)^2-\frac1{4x^2}
\end{align}
For large $x$ the last term is small, now try to argue that $e^u$ has to be considered as relatively  constant.

Comment: I don't understand how you constructed the definition of $u$. Could you please elaborate?